# latex code for block matrix

Tags: annotations

could anyone help me how to write in latex suc kind of matrix? I tried for the first one but didnt get exact form..thanks for helping[image: k]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[
    \begin{matrix}
       L_{\varepsilon_1} & & & & 0\\
       & L_{\varepsilon_2} & & & \\
       & & \ddots & & \\
       & & & L_{\varepsilon_r} & \\
       & & & & A_p+\lambda B_p\\
    \end{matrix}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) if you have `amsmath` package loaded, why than not use `\begin{bmatrix} ...\end{bmatrix}` from  it and erase `\left[` and `right]`?

Comment: @Zarko: just because I'm too lazy to remember english names for () [] || ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce as faithfully the image in the post:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{makebox, bigstrut}
\newcommand\mydot{\makebox*{$ L_{\varepsilon} $}{.}}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[%
\setlength\arraycolsep{-1.2pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-0.2ex}
\setlength\bigstrutjot{3pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{\varepsilon_1} & & & & & & 0\bigstrut[t]\\
 & L_{\varepsilon_2} \\  &  & \mydot \\  &  &  & \mydot \\& &  &  & \mydot \\
 & &  &  &  &  L_{\varepsilon_p}\\
  &  &  &  &  &  & A_p {+} \lambda B_p \bigstrut
\end{bmatrix}
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]